# Responsive Adsense Unit Breaking Bootstrap Panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, adsense

How do I prevent Adsense responsive unit placed similar to the code below from breaking out of the panel? In my experience the banner breaks the pannel and takes full width. The code used for Adsense responsive unit is the default code provided by Google.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-profile m-b-md">
        <div class="panel-body text-center" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- Thank You -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:block;"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
                 data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"
                 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: actual page]Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the ad unit is removed from the flow? It would be lot better if you add a sample markup of the ad, with any computed css on it.

Comment: Please add some sample markup that reproduces the problem. Doesn't have to be a full ad - just the same CSS or whatever they're using that causes the ad to mess up the column.

Comment: @MichaelCoker the only css I use to style the ads is display:block; I have discovered that the add centers itself in the middle of the page rather than the panel so it's neglecting the panel width and going to parent.

Comment: Reproduce it for us.

Comment: @MichaelCoker done, please see edit above, I have included an image and shown a picture, thank you so much

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't render an ad for me https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/yXZWpr

Comment: from your comments it looks like there is a absolute style somewhere that is causing it to take the window's width. why not add position: relative to the panel-body? that will make the element to take the panel's width

Comment: I am a guessing that u are trying to style content within an iframe here ?
If yes then here is something that you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512542/edit-css-of-elements-within-iframe?rq=1

Comment: you codepen URL is not rendering add, i believe some of you CSS is creating this issue, i suggest to past your live site URL to further debug.

Comment: There is an option to have responsive images in google adsense, however they only adapt to the page size on load, if you resize the page afterwards they will not resize with the page.

Answer (score 3):

I have set up a Plunker test and to me everything looks ok:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YTVHcR2SjMdEPyaM0Owa?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-profile m-b-md">
      <div class="panel-body text-center" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0">
        <!-- adsense responsive unit code -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9482555242423991" data-ad-slot="1928867468" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.adsbygoogle {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the unit I have is responsive so there shouldn't be overflow.... I discovered that the banner is taking page width and not panel width.

Comment: Why was this answer upvoted? You shouldn't have to add class properties to the ins tag. And like Techy said; overflow: hidden - you shouldn't have to use it. Anyone else figured this one out?

Comment: @PussInBoots - you are right. Of course you shouldn't. This is a working hack, not a fix for Google markup. Do you have a better solution, please post it as an answer.