# change css property when WITHIN an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

**A.html**

```
<div class="X"></div>
<div class="Y"></div>
```

**B.html**

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="A.html">
```

When user visits **A.html** set div Y to `display: none`

When user visits **B.html** set div X to `display: none`

Comment: On `a.html` add `<style>.Y{display:none;}</style>` and on `b.html` add  `<style>.X{display:none;}</style>`

Comment: It's not easy to access the contents of an iframe. This has been answered many ways. Check this page, plus the links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512542/edit-css-of-elements-within-iframe

Answer (score 1):

**Just Use this script in A.html i hope u'll get your desire result !**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        var ref = document.referrer;
       if (path == '/A.html' && ref!='')
        {
            $('[class="Y"]').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $('[class="X"]').css('display', 'none');
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. You can't simply access the contents of the iframe like that.

Comment: Still not working here but i reversed my downvote. it works for OP. not sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer and it worked. But for some reason, the original answer was deleted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var path = window.location.href;
        if(path=='http://www.example.com/A.html')
        {
            $('[class="Y"]').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $('[class="X"]').css('display', 'none');
        }

    });
```

Comment: yes, I've placed it into my `scripts.js` and loaded into `A.html`

Comment: Just tried again. It worked at first, but going back to page 1 failed. Have you tried going between pages a couple of times. Hopefully I'm not missing something.

Comment: weird, but it's still working here. tested couple of times!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add name property in your iframe
ex.

< iframe scrolling="no" src="A.html" name="Ahtml" >

then access using window.document.Ahtml.document (iframe has different document object)